# Angular ui-router dynamic parameter only for particular child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

UI-Router has a concept of dynamic state parameters that can be updated and not trigger a state change.  I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to specify a parameter as dynamic for only one particular child state.  Previously in ui-router v0.x you could accomplish this using the reloadOnSearch state option.

So for example

```
state('parentState', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '?{filter}',
    component: 'parentView',
})
.state('parentState.childOne', {
    abstract: false,
    url: '/childOne',
    views: {
        embeddedView: {
            component: 'childOne'
        }
    }
 })
 .state('parentState.childTwo', {
    abstract: false,
    url: '/childOne',
    views: {
        embeddedView: {
            component: 'childTwo'
        }
    }
 })
```

I would like 'filter' to be dynamic for childTwo and non dynamic for childOne.

I have tried to do something like this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 .state('parentState.childTwo', {
    abstract: false,
    url: '/childOne',
    params: {
        filter: {
            dynamic: true,   
        }
    }
    views: {
        embeddedView: {
            component: 'childTwo'
        }
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by overriding the complete parameter definition. 
So, if the filter parameter is defined like this in `parentState`:

```
params: {
  filter: {
    dynamic: false
  }
}
```

you should be able to define it like you did to be dynamic in `childTwo`.

The reason why it does not work in your example is probable, that you did not initially define the parameter in the `parentState`.